# Abort an EventHandler?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, eventhandler, scheduling

How do I stop an `EventHandler`? I'm trying to allow the user unlimited inputs on the arrow keys UNTIL certain conditions are met, and then stop the `EventHandler` and move on to something else. How can I accomplish this?
I've tried:

```
EventHandler[
  content,
  {"LeftArrowKeyDown" :>  ({  action;   If[conditions, Abort[]];})
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> ({  action;  If[conditions, Abort[]]; })
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :>  ({  action;   If[conditions, Abort[]]; })
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> ({ action;  If[conditions, Abort[]];  })
}]
```

But Mathematica seems to ignore the `Abort[]` completely, though it will execute other commands within the `If` statements when the same conditions are met. What am I missing here??

Edit: Okay, my code was rather general and unclear. Here is a more concrete example of what I want:

```
pt = {0.5, 0.5};
EventHandler[
 Framed[Graphics[
   {{Red, Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}},
   PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True
   ]],
 {
  "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (
    pt -= {0.05,0};
    If[pt == {0, 0}, Abort[]]
    ),
  "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (
    pt +={0.05,0};
    If[pt == {0, 0}, Abort[]]
    ),
  "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (
    pt +={0,0.05};
    If[pt == {0, 0}, Abort[]]
    ),
  "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (
    pt -={0,0.05};
    If[pt == {0, 0}, Abort[]]
    )
  }
 ]
```

So, my goal is to allow unlimited movement around this plane by the Disk, until the user moves the Disk to the point (0,0), at which time I want Mathematica to stop allowing input and move on to a different task in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I;m not quite sure what are you after. the `action` is take whether `conditions` are True or Note. Abort aborts only a specific evaluation and each event triggers another one. Do you want to disable an event completely after conditions are met? Or do you want to tak an `action` when `conditions` are True? Or maybe something different?

Comment: I want to disable any further events completely when 'conditions' are True.

Comment: What Operating System are you own?

Comment: I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly, use a `SelectorPane` and hide `EventHandler` as soon as the condition is met:

```
pt = {0, .05};

pane = "dynamic";

graphics = Framed[Graphics[
   {{Red, Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}}, PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True]
];


eh = EventHandler[#,
    {
     "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (pt -= {0.05, 0}; check@pt),
     "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (pt += {0.05, 0}; check@pt),
     "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (pt += {0, 0.05}; check@pt),
     "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (pt -= {0, 0.05}; check@pt)}
    ] &;


   (* Norm will be better as there some subtleties with =={0,0}*)
check[pts_] := If[Norm[pts] < .01, pane = "static"; FinishDynamic[];];

Column[{
  PaneSelector[
   {"dynamic" -> eh@graphics, "static" -> graphics},
   Dynamic@pane

   ],
  Dynamic@pane}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues.

1. The floating-point arithmetic could result in a point close to (0, 0) without being equal to (0, 0). Use `Chop`.
2. The `Abort` happens after `pt` is updated in `EventHandler` . So sequence of events is

   - Press key.
   - Update to (0, 0) (actually, really close to (0, 0)).
   - Not (0, 0), so continue.
   - Press key again.
   - Update to not (0, 0).
   - Not (0, 0), so continue.

You need move zero check to the start of the `EventHandler` and use `Chop` post arithmetic to succeed in the check.

```
pt = {0.5, 0.5};
EventHandler[
 Framed[Graphics[{{Red, Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}}, PlotRange -> 1, 
   Axes -> True]], {
  "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (If[pt == {0, 0}, Print["Move on"]; Abort[]]; 
     pt -= {0.05, 0}; pt = Chop /@ pt; ),
  "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (If[pt == {0, 0}, Print["Move on"]; Abort[]]; 
     pt += {0.05, 0}; pt = Chop /@ pt;),
  "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (If[pt == {0, 0}, Print["Move on"]; Abort[]]; 
     pt += {0, 0.05}; pt = Chop /@ pt; ),
  "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (If[pt == {0, 0}, Print["Move on"]; Abort[]]; 
     pt -= {0, 0.05}; pt = Chop /@ pt;)}]
```

Hope this helps.